# resize image in python so it can be saved from being stretch

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, python-imaging-library, xhtml2pdf

do anyone you know anything I can use to create functionality of CSS property -> " object-fit:scale-down " while generating pdf if images are coming in a different aspect ratio i tried it with giving only one place fixed or passing the height/ weight css based on height 20% greater then width then moving it to vertically rectangle box if the width is greater then height 20% moving to horizontal box if it's under 20% difference moving it to a square box but none of that works and images end up showing stretch. any logic or workaround will be helpful if possible i want to use PIL and achieve this...

Language- python3 
library used- jinja,xhtml2pdf, PIL

sample jinja code that is getting converted into pdf later

```
<img src="{{path}}" style="height:{{height}};width:{{width}};"  />
```

Python code tried

```
try:
                #logo fixes for diffrent size of logo
                im = Image.open('something')
                width,height = im.size
                #logic if logo is higher then 20% of width then it's vertically image if width is more then 20% of height then it's comes under horizontal catogory (20*width)/100  default is 2cm to 2cm for square image
                if height+(20*width)/100>width and height!=width: #horizontal 
                    data['width']='2cm' 
                    data['height']='4cm' 
                elif width+(20*height)/100>height and height!=width: #vertical
                    data['width']='4cm' 
                    data['height']='2cm' 
                else: #default
                    data['width']='2cm' 
                    data['height']='2cm' 
except Exception as imageerror:
    data['width']='2cm' 
    data['height']='2cm'
```

Comment: Please explain your desired logic in more detail and in more than one line. Your comment doesn't go well with your code or with the text above. An example would be also helpful.

Comment: @chillking for example...if the image size is 215X215 I will treat it as a square image. if the (500X215) height is greater than the width then I treat it as a vertical rectangle image and if the (215X500)width is greater than the height I will treat it as a rectangle image.  it working in some scenarios but for some image is getting stretched. i hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: okay, and an if-condition `if width > height: ... else: ...` doesn't suit this? If for example the height should be at least 20% larger than the width I would do `if height > 1.2*width: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
  image = Image.open('something')
  image.thumbnail((700,700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  image.save('something','JPEG',quality=100) #replace existing file
  height,width = image.size
except exception as e:
  #Size extraction failed Print e 
  pass
```

---

this way we can provide maximum boundaries for my images and PIL will take care of resizing and pass me the height and width of the image that fits in that boundaries ...Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite follow your logic with `30%` but something like this would work:

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('./image.png')

width, height = image.size

if width * 1.3 > height:
    new_height = width
    new_width = width
else:
    new_height = height
    new_width = height

image.resize([new_width, new_height]).save('./new_image.png')
```

Comment: please check i have added question with my logic